# Use of unresolved identifier 'Auth'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

I kept getting this error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Auth'

[image]

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://app-project.firebaseio.com")
    let usersReference = ref.child("Users")
    let id = usersReference.childByAutoId().key

    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: { (result, error) in
        let token = result?.instanceID
        let values = ["phone": phone,"CreatedAt":dateString,"UpdatedAt":dateString,"id":id as Any,"token":token as Any] as [String : Any]
        usersReference.child(id!).setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err.self as Any)
                return
            }
            print("Successfully saved user in Firebase DB")

        })

    })

}
```

---

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'project' do
   pod 'Charts'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
   pod 'Firebase/Database'
   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end
```

---

I already use this on top of my file

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
```

I tried to rebuild, still seeing it.

Restart XCode, rebuild still seeing it.

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: What's with all the close votes here? It's not a typo by any reasonable definition, and future readers could easily run into the same problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to

```
import FirebaseAuth
```

Comment: I thought `import Firebase` should take care of this - no ?

Comment: No , you have to import it

Comment: Ok, I did that, and the error seems to go aways. Thanks.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora make sure app is opened from workspace and you installed `pod 'Firebase/Auth'`

Comment: Both are there still facing same issue

Comment: This worked but can you explain why? Even google's documentation has it to only `import Firebase`.

Answer (score 1):

let include  'Firebase/Auth' in you pod file.Then type in your terminal pod install.Then import FirebaseAuth.